# SMTP server unexpectedly disconnected error when sending emails using mailgun service and MailKit in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, smtp, mailgun

I'm facing an issue when trying to send emails using the MailKit library in an ASP.NET Core application. The emails are sent successfully on my local machine, but when I deploy the application to a remote server (IIS), I encounter the following exception:

**Exception: Failed to send the email: The SMTP server has unexpectedly disconnected.**
EmailSender Class:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI.Services;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using MimeKit;
using MimeKit.Text;
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using MailKit.Security;

namespace syngri_web_app.Services
{
    public class EmailSender : IEmailSender
    {
        private readonly MailgunSettings _mailgunSettings;

        public EmailSender(IOptions<MailgunSettings> mailgunSettings)
        {
            _mailgunSettings = mailgunSettings.Value;
        }

        public async Task SendEmailAsync(string email, string subject, string htmlMessage)
        {
            try
            {
                var mimeMessage = new MimeMessage();
                mimeMessage.From.Add(new MailboxAddress("Excited Admin", "foo@" + _mailgunSettings.Domain));
                mimeMessage.To.Add(new MailboxAddress("Excited User", email));
                mimeMessage.Subject = subject;
                mimeMessage.Body = new TextPart(TextFormat.Html)
                {
                    Text = htmlMessage
                };

                using (var client = new MailKit.Net.Smtp.SmtpClient())
                {
                    client.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (s, c, h, e) => true;

                    await client.ConnectAsync("smtp.mailgun.org", 587, SecureSocketOptions.StartTls);
                    client.AuthenticationMechanisms.Remove("XOAUTH2");

                    await client.AuthenticateAsync("postmaster@"+_mailgunSettings.Domain+"", _mailgunSettings.ApiKey);

                    await client.SendAsync(mimeMessage);
                    await client.DisconnectAsync(true);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Log the exception details
                Console.WriteLine("An exception occurred while sending the email: " + ex.ToString());
                if (ex.InnerException != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Inner Exception: " + ex.InnerException.ToString());
                }
                throw new Exception("Failed to send the email: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Controller Code:

```
        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]

        public async Task<IActionResult> Forget(UserDto request)
        {

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var user = await userManager.FindByEmailAsync(request.Email);
                if (user != null && !user.EmailConfirmed)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("message", "Email not confirmed yet");
                    ItoastNotification.Error("Something went Wrong");
                    return View(request);

                }
                if (user == null) {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("message", "Email not Exist");
                    ItoastNotification.Error("Something went Wrong, Please inter valid email");
                    return View(request);
                }
                var code = await userManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user);
                code = WebEncoders.Base64UrlEncode(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(code));
                var callbackUrl = Url.Action(
                    "ResetPassword",
                    "Account",
                    new { area = "", code, request.Email },
                    protocol: Request.Scheme
                );
                var emailMessage = $"Please reset your password by <a href='{HtmlEncoder.Default.Encode(callbackUrl)}'>clicking here</a>.";
                await emailSender.SendEmailAsync(request.Email, "Reset Password", emailMessage);

                ItoastNotification.Success("Reset Email Has been Sent Please Check your Email");
                return RedirectToAction("Login");
            }
            foreach (var error in ModelState.Values.SelectMany(v => v.Errors))
            {
                // Handle or log the validation error messages
                var errorMessage = error.ErrorMessage;
                ItoastNotification.Error("Something went Wrong: "+errorMessage);
                break;
            }
            
            return View(request);
        }
```

I've verified that the SMTP server settings are correct, and the emails are successfully sent from my local machine. However, the issue arises only when deploying to the remote server.

Comment: Read the mail server webpage to find smtp settings.  There is more than one way of connecting.  Server usually required encrypted credentials (not user name and password), the account has to be valid, and the FROM address and credentials have to be the same.

Comment: @jdweng Thanks for your response!
I'm using the SMTP settings https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/quickstart-sending.html#send-via-smtp and the emails send successfully on my local host.

However, the problem arises when deploying to a remote server running IIS. Despite following the documentation's settings, I'm encountering the "SMTP server has unexpectedly disconnected" issue.

Is there any specific consideration or configuration I might be missing when deploying an ASP.NET Core application using MailKit for SMTP email sending on a remote IIS server?

Comment: The IIS is not allowing a connection to a remote SMTP server. It is using port forwarding to take port 587 to a email server on the IIS instead of your mailgun email server.  You need to talk to an admin on the IIS.  Check to see if they hare a email relay that you can use to forward your email.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_mail_relay

Comment: We were using MailKit and when deployed to a remote IIS Server, emails were not sent out. Issue ended up being a firewall software. Also, make sure that the TLS is 1.2 or higher.

Comment: Keep in mind that just because you have TLS 1.2 on both ends doesn't mean they agree on the same cipher suites etc. You'd need to familiarize yourself with how to check that, such as using Nmap and IIS Crypto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my issue by updating my emailSender class with the following code:

```
var smtpClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.mailgun.org")
{
    Port = 587,
    Credentials = new NetworkCredential(_mailgunSettings.UserName, _mailgunSettings.Password),
    EnableSsl = false
};

var mailMessage = new MailMessage
{
    From = new MailAddress("hello@gmail.io"),
    Subject = subject,
    Body = formattedHtmlMessage,
    IsBodyHtml = true
};

mailMessage.To.Add(email);

await smtpClient.SendMailAsync(mailMessage);
```

Comment: Am getting error: Unable to read data from the transport connection: net_io_connectionclosed.